# curl с++ https g++ Поделитесь уже собранной библиотекой

Tags: curl, g++, openssl, codeblocks

Не могу скомпилировать curl OpenSSL так как мне нужен доступ к https

Простой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl\curl.h>
#include <string>




// функция, вызываемая cURL для записи полученных данных
std::string curlBuffer;


int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  char curlErrorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curlErrorBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.co.uk");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res = CURLE_OK)
    {
        std::cout<<"ok\n";
    }
     std::cout<<"error:" << res << " "<<curlErrorBuffer<< "\n";

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

выдает ошибку Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl уже на стадии выполнения

Перелопатил кучу инфы, говорят что нужно скомпилировать с поддержкой OpenSSL но мой cmake говорит не найден модуль OpenSSL бред какой то. Уверен у многих под windows 10 собрана библиотека поделитесь плиз.
Code bloks

---

Вопрос решён был получен прямой ответ от Pak Uula Не понимаю почему комент так как ето ответ. Отметил его.

Функцией std::cout
Проверка показала что теперь посли скачивания сборки с сайта curl ,которую я сам почему то не нашёл,  что OpenSSL есть теперь.

```
ste::cout<<curl_version()<<'\n';
```

```
libcurl/7.80.0 OpenSSL/3.0.0 (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.46.0 libgsasl/1.10.0
```

Да возникла новая проблема проверки сертификата но ето уже совсем другой вопрос

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

```
// не проверять сертификат удаленного сервера
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Решен отключением проверки, плохо, но для моего бота телеграм который в групу отправляет кто присоединен кто отсоединён к серверу ето не критично.

Вопрос задан вопрос получен правда в коментах к воросу

 Благодарю всех за помощь

Comment: какая ОС windows/linux?

Comment: Windows 10 64 32 думаю не важно но у меня 64

Comment: Бинарник из https://curl.se/windows/ вам не подходит?

Comment: Я искал не нашёл. Благодарю за ссылку именно то что нужно.

Comment: Скорее всего у них компиляции без поддержки ssl иле мой компилятор не перекомпилировал тело, возможно проблема в другом, буду разбираться.

Comment: SSL Вроде поддерживает, значит ошыбка в другом

Comment: libcurl/7.80.0 OpenSSL/3.0.0 (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.46.0 libgsasl/1.10.0
error:0 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: curl_version() Отобразило то что прокомментировал выше ну и текст ошибки

Comment: По идее Schannel использует сертификаты из реестра. Я никогда не пользовался Schannel в Windows, поэтому не могу сказать, почему он не находит сертификат. Простой способ обойти эту проблему - отключить проверку сертификатов опцией [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html)

Answer (score -1):

под Windows самое простое - использовать cmake-gui для конфигурации libcurl.
Предварительно установите openssl и укажите соответствующие параметры при конфигурации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В результате вывод должен получиться примерно следующий

```
curl version=[7.74.0]
Enabled features: SSL IPv6 libz AsynchDNS SSPI alt-svc SPNEGO Kerberos NTLM MultiSSL HTTPS-proxy
Enabled protocols: DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS LDAP MQTT POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP
Enabled SSL backends: OpenSSL Schannel
Configuring done
```

после этого можете генерировать makefile и собирать libcurl с поддержкой ssl

Comment: Я  пробовал установить оно просить перл сайт перл требует регистрацию а скачав мне все равно предоставляется не скомпилированный код. По этому и прошу готовый билд. Я пробовал у меня не получилось.

Comment: Но я уже получил ссылку спасибо. Если дадите ссылку ssl инсталлятор я не против на будущие, тогда попробую скомпилировать повторно, а пока готовым билом воспользуюсь.

Comment: Хотя скорее инструкцию по установке

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/

Comment: честно говоря и не знаю что там описывать. собирается как любая другая либа с cmake - несколько итераций конфигурирования, пока не скажет что все устраивает и вперед

Comment: так вы скинули сборку для g++ не инсталлер , как к cmake прикрутить?